# Resolve error related to using DISTINCT with the OVER clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I encountered a problem with SQL Server which displayed the following error message:

> Msg 10759, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause.

This occurred while executing a specific query:

```
WITH users_login AS 
(
    SELECT 
        CAST(l.start_at AS DATE) AS session_date,
        UPPER(l.user_id) AS user_id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT l.session_id) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(l.start_at AS DATE), UPPER(l.user_id)) AS logins_cnt,
        ...
    FROM 
        dbo.user_login l
),
...
```

The issue stemmed from the use of `COUNT(DISTINCT l.session_id)` in combination with the `OVER` clause, which SQL Server does not support.

In search of a solution, I consulted various online resources, including Stackoverflow. The recommended fix was to include `DENSE_RANK()` in the query.

However, when using `DENSE_RANK()`, I get a new error instructing to add an `ORDER BY` clause, despite already having one in the query:

> Msg 4112, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> The function 'DENSE_RANK' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.

Here's the adjusted query:

```
WITH users_login AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ...
        COUNT(DISTINCT l.session_id), 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(l.start_at AS DATE), UPPER(l.user_id)) AS logins_cnt,
        ...
    FROM 
        ...
    ORDER BY 
        l.session_id
),
...
```

Additionally, the SQL Server environment details are as follows:

```
SQL Server Management Studio        15.0.18424.0
Operating System                    10.0.17763
```

Comment: Is column `session_id` nullable?

Comment: no. nvarchar(50) not null

Comment: `OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)`.

Comment: When providing your SQL Server version, we need `select @@version` not the version of SSMS which is only a client UI

Comment: It would help if you added sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: are you trying to calculate how many unique `session_id` for each `start_at`? if so, does `group by` instead of window function not helping?

Comment: @BagusTesa how to do group by? where?
@jarlh it's I did: `UPPER(l.user_id) ORDER BY l.start_at)  AS logins_cnt` and got another error: `Column 'dbo.user_login.start_at' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
No column name was specified for column 3 of 'users_login'.`

Comment: @Jon i'm not sure for the reason to stick with window function given all you need **a single aggregate value** from a set of criteria ran over the entire set. of which you can tackle it with either subquery or outer apply. i'm not sure what you exactly need though, given no sample input and output provided. that being said, [pick your poison](https://dbfiddle.uk/UQoMnhoi) as they produce similar result to siggemannen answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
COUNT(DISTINCT <expression>) OVER (...)
```

is not yet implemented. You coul use a*

```
ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (... ORDER BY <expression> DESC) AS N,
```

then and use

```
COUNT(N) OVER(PARTITION BY ....)  WHERE N = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate it by only counting the first occurances of each session row:

```sql
create table #logins (session_id int, start_at datetime, user_id nvarchar(30))

insert into #logins
values  (1, '20231206 10:30', 'test')
,   (1, '20231206 11:30', 'test')
,   (1, '20231206 12:30', 'test')
,   (2, '20231206 13:30', 'test')
,   (1, '20231206 12:30', 'test2')
,   (2, '20231206 13:30', 'test3')

;with cte as (
        select  *
        ,   COUNT(CASE WHEN uniqueSess = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY session_date, user_id) AS cnt
        from (
            select  CAST(l.start_at AS DATE) AS session_date
            ,   UPPER(l.user_id) AS user_id
            ,   session_id
            ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(l.start_at AS DATE), user_id, session_id order by @@spid) as uniqueSess
            from #logins l
        ) x
    )
select *
from cte
```

Since you cannot wrap multiple window functions inside each other, you have to create a subquery.

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(l.start_at AS DATE), user_id, session_id order by @@spid)` creates a counter of 1,2,3 for every unique session row. Since you don't care about order, i use @@spid as order by.

`COUNT(CASE WHEN uniqueSess = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY session_date, user_id) AS cnt` this conditionally aggreggates so only first row counts towards the unique session count.

Output:

| session_date | user_id | session_id | uniqueSess | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-06 | TEST | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2023-12-06 | TEST | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2023-12-06 | TEST | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2023-12-06 | TEST | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2023-12-06 | TEST2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-12-06 | TEST3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |